# is there a way of reding individual cells in an access table using row and column indexing

Tags: c#, ms-access

Hey:) am trying to display text in a singe cell of an access table in a text box how can I read that specific cell am new to databases so I can only go as far as connecting to the database itself.

Comment: Hey Kevin, welcome to SO. Your question is a bit vague, please see [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far?

Comment: No.  Access read one row of a data table from the data base at a time.  Once you get the row then you need to get index of the column.  There is no way in access of advancing to a particular row without getting one row at a time using Read().  If you need to do a lot of row column index then I recommend dumping entire access table into a c# DataTable which allows row and column access.

Comment: thanks a bunch :) that really helped I hadn't really put the data table into perspective

Answer (score 0):

You can read the table as a recordset, move to the record and read the field:

```
Dim rs     As DAO.Recordset

Dim Row    As Long
Dim Column As Long
Dim Value  As Variant

' Example. First is no. 1:
Row = 15
Column = 2

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From Tabel1 Order By Dato")
' Read all records.
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst
' Go to record.
rs.Move Row - 1
' Read field.
Value = rs.Fields(Column - 1).Value

Debug.Print Value

rs.Close
```